# set session value as array in code igniter 2

Tags: codeigniter-2

How do I set value into the session as an array using Code Igniter:

I want the session structure like this :

```
CI_Session Object
( 
[field_value] => Array
        (

            [function_time] => 1384698101

        )
```

Comment: I think I could use this :$field_value['function_time'] = 1384698101; 
        $this->session->field_value = $field_value;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you pass into `set_userdata` will be set in the session:

```
$data = array(
    'field_value' => array(
        'function_time' => 1384698101
    )
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

If you want it as part of the session object, you could:

```
$this->session->field_value = array('function_time' => 1384698101);
```

However, I'm not sure why you'd want to do this. The data will only be available during the request when you set it ... only the data stored in the `userdata` is actually saved in the session and available on subsequent requests.

Comment: this would include the $data in the [userdata] , but I want the array inside a separate [field_value] for the CI session

Comment: thanks dleiftah.. And after that, can I retrieve the value using  $this->session->field_value('function_time') ?

Comment: You would retrieve it with `$this->session->field_value['function_time']`, but it will only be available during the request where you set it. The other variables are not stored in the session data and, thus, are not available on subsequent requests.

Comment: I see, I didn't know the data will only be available during the request. Originaly I want the session be more structurised. I guest I will use userdata session instead. Thanks

Comment: The session object is merely the *session handler* ... the `userdata` section of the session object is the actual session data and you can structure that however you want. If you're using the built-in functions (`set_userdata`, `all_userdata`, `userdata`) then the inner-workings will be transparent to you and you can structure and use the session data however you want.